# Managed Properties not Appearing in CSWP in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I am not seeing any of my custom managed properties in the property dropdown in the webpart properties of my Content Search WebPart in my SharePoint Online tenant.

Here is what I've done:
Site columns were created, added to custom content types which were in turn added to a list, content was added to the list, content was crawled.

The managed properties are configured and correctly mapped to their corresponding crawled properties.  The options on the managed properties are: Searchable, Queryable, Retrievable, Safe.

Using the SharePoint Search Query Tool I can query against the site collection and DO SEE these managed properties being returned with data in them so I know they are valid.

Problem is I don't see them in the property drop-down when editing the webpart properties of a Content Search Web Part. Should that list show all managed properties set to 'Retrievable' in the search schema?  I thought it was supposed to. 
When I search within the site collection for the managed property from Search Schema it does appear. I have also created a custom display template whereby I want to bring in these custom managed properties, but that is also failing as it doesn't seem to recognize these managed properties (which makes sense since I'm not seeing them in the dropdown of the webpart properties). Since this is SharePoint Online, I have waited a day and then another day to ensure the updates are being propagated out to my site collection, but I still do not see them.

I'm very familiar with doing this in SharePoint 2013, but this is the first time I've ran into problems doing it in SPO. Note: although I don't think this is relevant, this is on a cross-site publishing page.

I would appreciate any ideas you think may be the problem. I'm at a loss what it might be.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue, and managed to solve it by free typing the managed property in the drop down box rather than waiting for it to appear in the drop down list. As long as it is successfully mapped to a crawled property then it should work. My question is [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190578/managed-properties-missing-in-cswp) for reference (I wasn't able to comment on your post originally due to just joining the site, so I wanted to be sure to share my findings). Hope this helps.