# Managed Properties Missing in CSWP

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I'm having the same issue detailed in this 
[Original Post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186810/managed-properties-not-appearing-in-cswp-in-sharepoint-online?newreg=afe8879289de4ebcafdb77c8066e58d4) that unfortunately hasn't found an answer. I've just joined the community hence was unable to comment or reach out to the original poster so I apologise for the additional question, however are there any ideas on the cause?

[image]

Comment: I have not used SharePoint online. But for sp2013 on-premise, you need to find out the "crawled property" for your particular metadata first. Then map the crawled property to managed property. Then you will see the managed property you need.

Comment: BTW, can you use this property in Search Center?

Comment: @Mark I can see the crawled property mapped to the managed property. When I search for the property it successfully returns results (the body text of an announcement), however in the CSWP I still don't have the option to select it from the drop down of property mappings in order to display it in the CSWP results.

Comment: in the dropdown, I remember the last option is "show more"? I don't have SP2013 on hand. If possible can you add screenshot shows which "drop down" you are referring to?

Comment: @Mark Have added the screenshot above, had some resolution issues with my screen so please disregard those vertical lines. There isn't an option to show more in this particular drop down, but my managed property is not available.

Comment: Please go thru option 1-4, hope it helps: [reference](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/03/displaying-right-data-in-content-search.html)

Comment: Turns out I can free type the property in the drop down bow rather than waiting for it to appear in the drop down list, as long as it has been mapped to a crawled property (which it has). Can't believe I didn't think to just type it in until now! Thanks for your help @Mark

Comment: lol.. you can type in the dropdownbox you labeled in yellow? I didn't know. Could you answer the `Original Post `?

Comment: Yea, haven't face palmed that hard in a while. Have just answered the original.